# Display Product Color with Product Size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got value from multiple select 2 drop-down 
value like this

```
var color =  [Red,Black];
var size = [41,42,43];
```

I want display in table  size and color using JavaScript or JQuery.

Result should be like this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>COlor</th>
    <th>Size</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Red</th>
    <th>41</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Red</th>
    <th>42</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Red</th>
    <th>43</th>
  </tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <th>41</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <th>42</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <th>43</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th>
    Color
  </th>
  <th>
    Size
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to loop on each possible value you have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var color =  ["Red","Black"];
  var size = [41,42,43];

  var table = jQuery("#myTable");
  for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<size.length; j++){
        var row = "<tr><td>"+color[i] + "</td><td>" + size[j] +"</td></tr>"
      table.append(row)
    }
  }
})
```

The output will be:

```
Color   Size
Red     41
Red     42
Red     43
Black   41
Black   42
Black   43
```